# Passing info from Facebook to UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

When my app first starts, it shows a main page to log in to Facebook.  Then, it goes to the `UITabBarController`. The code that I have in my app delegate is the following:

```
//this is the .h
@interface NMeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainViewController *controller;
    UITabBarController *tabBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *controller;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end

//this is the .m of the app delegate
#import "NMeAppDelegate.h"

@implementation NMeAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabBar;
@synthesize controller;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    controller = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:tabBar.view];
    [window addSubview:controller.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Inside of `MainViewController`, I actually have a UserInfo object, which has all of the information that I need for the UITabBarController. The problem is that after getting this info in the `UITabViewController`, how do I pass this UserInfo to the UITabBarController` or possible the ViewController that is inside the UITabBarController so they were able to access this UserInfo? How to do this?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: I'm afraid what you were hoping for didn't come to pass: Your question doesn't make sense :) Please clearly state what you're trying to achieve and what is happening instead.

Comment: revised the question a bit, I hope it helps... crossing my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have an instance of your UserInfo object available to the tab bar controller. probably pass it into a instance variable of type `UserInfo` in your UItabBarController/each view controller whenever you transition into the specified controller.

edit: you should really have this passed into the view Controller it needs to be in (since it doesn't appear you have a custom UITabBarController subclass), or you could use a shared `UserInfo` variable in your app delegate to keep up with the information.

But as the commenter said, the question is not very clear at all and i could be completely misunderstanding what you want to do.

Hope that helps.